# How to solve 413 error in chrome browser

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, google-chrome

Ι have the following code in jQuery

```
var method = "SaveUploadedOffer";
var url = "/Handler/UserControlHandler.ashx";
  var data = { 'method': method, 'UploadedObj': 
            JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(Selected))};
            $.post(url, data,
                    function (result) {    
                    $("#preloader").css("display","block");                
                        var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                        if (obj.IsSucess==true) { 
                            self.SelectedPurpose(null);
                            self.SelectedPropertyType(null);
                            jAlert(obj.Message,"Alert...");    
                            $("#preloader").css('display', 'none');    
                            if(obj.Message=="Session expired, please login to continue")
                            {
                                    $('#popup_ok').on('click', function(e){ 
                                     window.location = "../rental/home.aspx";             
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 $('#popup_ok').on('click', function(e){ 
                                     window.location = "../user/dashboard.aspx";             
                                });
                            }

                        }
                        else {

                            jAlert("Something went wrong, please try again later","Error...");  
                            $("#preloader").css("display","block");                        
                        }
                    });
```

This code is working fine in firefox but in chrome it gives me an error.

please tell me how can I resolve this error.

[image]

Comment: Add useragent to your request headers : request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";

Comment: @jdweng any specific reason to add `request.UserAgent` in request header? can you please explain it in detail?

Comment: When a client connects to a server a negotiation occurs using the html headers to find a compatible mode of operation.  The server doesn't know what browser is being used and defaults to a particular browser when user agent isn't specified.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it is working in firefox but, `413 errors` occur when the request body is larger than the server is configured to allow.

In IIS Set the `uploadreadaheadsize` config setting

Below are the steps to set `uploadReadAheadSize` in `IIS 8.5`

- Open IIS
- Navigate under Default Web Site
- Scroll down to Management and open Configuration Editor
- Select following section (drop down at the top) system.webServer and expand it, then locate serverRuntime
- you'll find there the current value of uploadReadAheadSize value, which you can change

Answer (score 0):

i have change my web.config like

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <!-- This will handle requests up to 20MB -->
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480" timeout="3600" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

<!-- IIS Specific Targeting (noted by the system.webServer section) -->
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <!-- This will handle requests up to 20MB -->
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20971520" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

and now it works fine for both firefox and chrome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If in Chrome, just reset browser to default settings.  Worked for me.